# Sum of Rows and display in new column

Tags: tableau-api

As shown in the image I need to arrive at values displayed in C column:

In C column 1370311 value is arrived by adding A column from row 1 to 5
The second column is derived by adding A column from row 2 to 5
Similarly all values are computed.

I also need to compute values for rows 7 -10 using same logic,

How can I build a calculation the does this in tableau.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What are the other dimensions of your data?  You may be able to create a Calculated Field using an IF expression to aggregate on the dimension.

Comment: I have a dimension test. The data you see are data of that particular dimension

Comment: I don't think Tableau is suited for this purpose.  Tableau builds or calculates on data that is already relational in some way, whereas here it seems that you are attempting to define relations and then build calculations. My advice would be to have this done in your data source.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a monthly value (column A) and are trying to also display the year to date value (column C).

To do this you need to create a calculated field with an IF statement that basically explains to Tableau how to handle this data.

```
IF [some_parameter]=Jan AND [month]=Jan THEN sum([value])

ELSEIF [some_parameter]=Feb AND ([month]=Jan OR [month]=Feb) THEN sum([value])

ELSEIF [some_parameter]=Mar AND ([month]=Jan OR [month]=Feb OR [month]=Mar) THEN sum([value])

etc. all the way up to:

ELSEIF [some_parameter]=Dec AND ([month]=Jan OR [month]=Feb OR [month]=Mar OR [month]=Apr OR [month]=May OR [month]=Jun OR [month]=Jul OR [month]=Aug OR [month]=Sep OR [month]=Oct OR [month]=Nov OR [month]=Dec) THEN sum([value])
```

Basically this says, if it's January, only show me January. But if it's February then show me both January and February, etc. up to "if it's December, show me everything".

[some_parameter] doesn't necessarily need to be a parameter, it just needs to be whatever you are using to distinguish the rows. Some kind of field that will distinguish which if statement (which month) to use in the calculated field.